# How to import MS Sql Server tables to KSQL with Kafka connect

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Hi I am trying to import all tables present on remote SQL Server to KSQL topics
this is my file properties

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector
name=sqlservertest
tasks.max=1
initial.database=$$DATABASE
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://$$IP:1433;databaseName=$$DATABASE;user=$$USER;
username=$$USER
password=$$PASS
server.name=$$IP
server.port=1433
topic.prefix=sqlservertest
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
mode=bulk
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

than i do

```
confluent load sqlservertest -d /opt/kakfkaconf/sqlservertest.properties
```

and in the log

```
confluent log connect -f
```

it shows

```
[2018-10-10 14:18:43,856] INFO Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:868)
```

it run correctly but it doesn't import anything, the topic remain empty

```
confluent status sqlservertest 
{
  "name": "sqlservertest",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "10.132.0.2:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "source"
}
```

I have chenaged also the properties

```
name=mssql
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector
tasks.max=2
initial.database=$$DB
username=$$USER
password=$$PASS
server.name=$$IP
server.port=1433
change.tracking.tables=$$SCHEMA.$$TABLE
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
topic.prefix=$$DB
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

but i am getting this error

```
[2018-10-10 15:06:09,216] ERROR Exception thrown while querying for ChangeKey{databaseName=$$DB, schemaName=$$SCHEMA, tableName=$$TABLE} (io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService:94)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Exception thrown while getting metadata for ChangeKey{databaseName=$$DB, schemaName=$$SCHEMA, tableName=$$TABLE}
        at io.confluent.connect.cdc.CachingTableMetadataProvider.tableMetadata(CachingTableMetadataProvider.java:64)
        at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.queryTable(QueryService.java:108)
        at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.processTables(QueryService.java:92)
        at io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.QueryService.run(QueryService.java:67)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:60)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: i am checking the log confluent log connect and it connect correctly to the server Ms Sql but nothing else is happening

Comment: What is the result of a POST request on `{{kafka-connect-url}}/connectors/{{connector-name}}/status`?

Comment: confluent status sqlservertest 
{
  "name": "sqlservertest",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "10.132.0.2:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "source"
}

Comment: i updated my question with more details

Comment: What are the names of your table,db, schema etc. ?

Comment: you think that is related with the names? they are similar to any command or or statement

Comment: This error could be quite tricky when debugging. Any special characters (e.g. dot, comma etc) in table, db or schema names can sometimes cause such errors.

Comment: the name of db have upper case like " DbNet" and table name is in upper case USER schema name is totally lower case

Comment: Are you able to access the MSSQL logs and look what queries are trying to be ran?

Comment: Nope, let me try, thanks very much

Comment: there are no log for errors. I dunno how to debug it

Answer (score 3):

I found the real cause of this error, Kafka connector are using the functions that is present just in MS Sql server 2012, in particular IFF and boolan comparison in function

```
select IFF(1>2,'OK','KO');
select (1>2) as bool;
```

that are NOT working on MS Sql 2008

**The real cause is that Conflunet MSSQL Connector is made just for MS SQL Server 2012 and above and I am runnning version 2008**

I decompiled the library **kafka-connect-cdc-mssql** and adjusted the sql code to be compliant with sqlserver 2008 and now it's working.

Maybe I will push it to github to make it available for everybody

Comment: Hey I have the same error and same version of mssql. Can you please share your code on github? Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello, if you want we can chat privately. I'm blocked with this.